# Faunus graph not printing nodes without using side effect from gremlin shell

Tags: gremlin, titan, faunus

I'm trying to print a graph in Faunus (v0.4.0) where a node has any edges (incoming or outgoing). From the gremlin shell, I tried:

```
g = FaunusFactory.open('faunus.properties')
g.V.filter("{it.bothE.hasNext()}").sideEffect("{println it}")
```

When I do this, I get a printout of all the nodes as I expected

But without the println, I do not.

According to [How do I write a for loop in gremlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427066/how-do-i-write-a-for-loop-in-gremlin), the gremlin terminal should print this info out for me, but it does not seem to.

Is there something specific I need to do to enable the printing from the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faunus and Gremlin are close to each other in terms of purpose and functionality but not identical.  The `filter` isn't producing a side-effect, which will be written to HDFS.  If you did:

```
g.V.filter("{it.bothE.hasNext()}").id
```

You could then view the list of ids matching that filter with something like:

```
hdfs.head('output',100)
```

to see the first 100 lines of the output.  If you need more than just the element identifier you could do a `transform` to get some of the element properties in there as well.  You might find these `hdfs` helper [tips](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/faunus/wiki/HDFS-Handling#useful-tricks) helpful.